# can any one help me to find this solution in java

Tags: java

Do the insert, update and delete operations using excel as database. Use minimum of 5 fields. ( Id,  name,  salary, Address, Experience).

I have designed program and  i getting this error
what is the meaning of this error and how to solve this error

Error: Could not find or load main class Write2Excel

if you have any demo program, can you please help me.

Comment: Check if your project, package name and / or class name are the same. Usually there is something wrong there if you get messages like that.

Comment: can you have any program on this task(Do the insert, update and delete operations using excel as database. Use minimum of 5 fields. ( Id, name, salary, Address, Experience).)